# Marking distances with QChainage Tool and Marker Lines (they differ)

Tags: qgis-3, qchainage

I have an issue with the markers created by the QChainage Tool and Marker Lines created in Layer Properties (under Symbology). I was trying to use the Marker Lines to create unlabeled intervals between the QChainage markers. The Marker Lines line up fine with the QChainage markers as long as I am zoomed out enough to see the origin. However, when I zoom in and lose sight of the origin, they no longer line up. See the zoomed-out image and zoomed-in image below:

[image: zoomed-out image]

[image: zoomed-in image]

Is there any way to prevent this problem, or am I trying to do something that is just not possible using Marker Lines?

I am using QGIS 3.10.4.

Comment: Just to confirm, your marker line symbology is using map units and both layers are in the same (projected) CRS?

Comment: Yes, both layers used CRS EPSG:26915 and the project CRS is set as EPSG:26915. QChainage used "Chainage every 1000 meters" and Marker Placement in marker line symbology is set to "with interval 100 map units."

Comment: Hm, yes, I am getting a similar issue. This is a bit concerning... Can't figure out a reason why this is happening just yet. Hopefully someone has an answer here.

Comment: I'm getting the same here, when exporting the layout as an atlas... I made us of the geometry generator to create the labels and wanted to combine them with the marker line. So here, it's only a single layer.

Answer (score 0):

I just found the following approach:
"Open project properties dialog > "General" tab > "General settings" group > Avoid artifacts when project is rendered as map tiles."
https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/22739#issuecomment-495859980

<s>So far this seems to solve the problem.</s>

While it corrects the artifacts for the data view, it doesn't for print layouts (in my case an atlas generation). Left you see the layout generation, richt the data view...
[image]